# Prove that a continuous periodic function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Does this proof work for the above problem:

Suppose on the contrary that $f$ is not bounded above on $[a, b]$. Then there
exists a sequence $x_n$ chosen from $[a, b]$ such that $f(x_n)>n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By the compactness of $[a, b]$ there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$
of $x_n$ such that $x_{n_k}\to c\in[a, b]$. But
then we have $f(x_{n_k})\to\infty$, since $f(x_n)$ does, but also $f(x_{n_k})\to f(c)$ by continuity.
Since $f(c)$ must be finite, this is a contradiction. Hence $f$ is bounded above; do we then have to show it is bounded below?

Comment: What is $[a,b]$? You need to prove that $f$ is bounded on reals. But that is the right idea: try to prove that $f$ is bounded on $[0, p]$ and then use the periodicity.

Comment: I thought I would generalise it to [a,b]. Couldn't you say that on the interval [x, x+p] that it is bounded by the boundedness theorem and because it is periodic it must be bounded on the reals

Comment: I hope you mean $p > 0$ instead of $p \ge 0$ - if $p = 0$ were allowed then every function would satisfy the definition.

Comment: Another possible approach would be: given $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_n) > n$, then for each $n$ you can add or subtract an integer multiple of $p$ from $x_n$ to get $y_n \in [0, p]$ such that $f(y_n) = f(x_n) > n$.  Then take a convergent subsequence of the $y_n$ and get your contradiction.

Comment: How would you write that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should localize $f$ to $[0,p]$ and then $f$ is bounded on $[0,p]$ with bound $M$, and hence on each $[np,(n+1)p]$ for each $n\in{\bf{Z}}$ with the same bound by the periodicity of $f$ because for $x\in[np,(n+1)p]$, $|f(x)|=|f(x-np)|\leq M$. Therefore, $M$ is a bound for $f$ on ${\bf{R}}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in{\bf{Z}}}[np,(n+1)p]$.

Comment: Isn't it from [x, x+p] ?

Comment: What is the $x$? Put $np$ for that and taking the union is the real line.

Comment: Is this a formal proof for this question?

Comment: Of course there is some details you need to write out to let it be a complete proof.

Comment: What would you write out?

Comment: Like $x\in[np,(n+1)p]$, then $|f(x)|=|f(x-np)|\leq M$.

Comment: Is this after the [np(n+1)p] point in your proof

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Could you please rewrite your answer in the complete way you have pointed out?

Answer (score 4):

The extreme value theorem for continuous functions states that every continuous function defined on a closed and bounded interval attains its maximum and minimum value. Thus, f(x)  is bounded on  the closed bounded interval $[0,p]$

Therefore there exists a positive rel number B such that $$|f(x)| \le B $$ for $$x\in [0,p]$$

The periodicity implies that it is bounded on real line because $$|f(kp+x)|=|f(x)| \le B $$ for all integers $k.$

Note that every real number could be represented as $ x+kp$ where $k$ is an integer and $x \in [0,p].$

Comment: Isn't it from [x, x+p] ?

Comment: Same result,  because it is periodic and you can start  the period at any point.

Comment: It is the same concept. You may start the interval at any point as long as the length of the interval is the period.

Comment: Is this a formal proof for this though?

Comment: Yes, it is a formal proof.

Comment: It seems rather short, is there any other detail that needs to be added?

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn I  have added some detail to my solution to make it more accessible to readers.